# quantikz - moving the $\psi_0$ down like the other $\psi$

Tags: quantikz

I would really appreciate if someone can help me move `$psi_0` to the bottom like the rest of the `$psi$`. Below is the code I used.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{quantikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}




    \begin{quantikz}[slice all,slice style={shorten <=-0.1cm,
    shorten >=-0.1cm},slice label style={yshift=-2.5cm}, slice titles = $\psi_{\col}$]
         \lstick {\ket{a}}  \slice[style={yshift=-2.5cm}]{$\psi_0$} & \ctrl{1} & \qw& \ctrl{1} & \qw \\
         \lstick {\ket{b}} & \targ{}  & \gate{R_Z(2 \gamma)} & \targ{}  & \qw 
    \end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with `quantikz` package, but it seems that you should have in matrix one column more:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{quantikz}
\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}
    \begin{quantikz}[
slice all,
slice style = {shorten <=-0.1cm,
               shorten >=-0.1cm},
slice label style = {yshift=-24mm}, 
slice titles = $\psi_{\fpeval{\col-1}}$
                    ]
\lstick {\ket{a}}  
    &   & \ctrl{1} & \qw    & \ctrl{1}  & \qw \\
%
\lstick {\ket{b}} 
    &   & \targ{}  & \gate{R_Z(2 \gamma)}   
                        & \targ{}  & \qw
    \end{quantikz}
\end{document}
```

This will give you:

[image]